# SNP coordinates to gene names

Tags: r, mapping, bioinformatics, genome

I have SNP ids and coordinates in a bed file provided by UCSC. I want to map them to their gene names.

```
chr1    9160974     9160975     rs1013578619    0   +
chr1    164528869   164528870   rs1016074293    0   +
chr1    192216772   192216773   rs1018731047    0   +
chr1    117157669   117157670   rs1022293363    0   +
chr1    33148118    33148119    rs1022386792    0   +
```

I have referred to many posts which suggest to use bedtools intersect, UCSC table browser etc but I am not able to get the successful results. Please suggest the options to use for this particular data.

Comment: This has been asked many times, have you tried anything? https://www.biostars.org/p/18522/

Comment: Yes, I have even gone through the link you have suggested. I have tried using SCAN but could map only few genes. I have used UCSC and got a bed file which specifies the position and stand again but no gene names. I have checked with dbSNP  which gave me only SNP IDs. I have thoroughly checked almost every related question in biostar, stackoverflow etc,.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.biostars.org/p/413/#418

Comment: Yes, I had gone through this but my data is too huge and mentioning so many values in the select query is difficult.

Comment: Are you familiar with R?

Comment: Yes, I am. I do use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [*biomaRt* package](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/biomaRt/inst/doc/biomaRt.html):

```r
# data
mySNPs <- read.table(text = "chr1    9160974     9160975     rs1013578619    0   +
chr1    164528869   164528870   rs1016074293    0   +
chr1    192216772   192216773   rs1018731047    0   +
chr1    117157669   117157670   rs1022293363    0   +
chr1    33148118    33148119    rs1022386792    0   +")
colnames(mySNPs) <- c("chr", "start", "end", "name", "x", "strand")

library(biomaRt)

snpmart = useMart(biomart = "ENSEMBL_MART_SNP", dataset = "hsapiens_snp")

# Check which filters and attributes we wan't to use:
# listAttributes(snpmart)
# listFilters(snpmart)

# result
getBM(attributes = c("refsnp_id", "chr_name", "chrom_start", "chrom_end", "ensembl_gene_stable_id"), 
      filters = c("snp_filter"), 
      values = mySNPs$name, 
      mart = snpmart)

#      refsnp_id chr_name chrom_start chrom_end ensembl_gene_stable_id
# 1 rs1013578619        1     9160975   9160975        ENSG00000228526
# 2 rs1016074293        1   164528870 164528870                       
# 3 rs1018731047        1   192216773 192216773        ENSG00000285280
# 4 rs1022293363        1   117157670 117157670        ENSG00000134258
# 5 rs1022386792        1    33148119  33148119        ENSG00000278997
# 6 rs1022386792        1    33148119  33148119        ENSG00000116525
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked for me. I am sure this post will be helpful for many people because most of the other posts suggest bedtools intersect which may not work always. Thanks again!